# Dropzone.js - only show progress of complete upload

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, upload, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js to upload files to my server. That's how the file looks like:

```
<div id="full_site">
    <form id="uploadFile" method="post" name="uploadFile" action="upload.php"
          class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable full-height">
        <span id="tmp-path"></span>
        <div class="dz-message"><b></b></div>
    </form>
</body>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

        Dropzone.options.uploadFile = {
            init: function () {
                this.on("success", function (file, responseText) {
                    file.previewTemplate.appendChild(document.createTextNode(responseText));
                });

                this.on("sending", function (file) {
                    $("#tmp-path").html('<input type="hidden" name="path" value="' + file.fullPath + '" />')
                });
            }
        };

        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#uploadFile", {
            url: "upload.php"
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I try to achieve is, that there are no upload previews shown any more, so they are no previews for each file any more, but a progress bar, that show's the overall process of the complete upload (maybe only show an error if there is one, but otherwise do not show every single item). Is there any way I can achieve this?

**Edit**: an optional point would be to show this progress bar in a bootstrap modal, so it doesn't change anything on the site when you upload something.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple parts to this. First, you want to avoid having any preview template for items that have been queued or are uploading. I think dropzone needs some kind of object, so you can basically do this by setting the previewTemplate option in the dropzone initialization to a div with nothing inside of it:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#uploadFile", {
    url: "upload.php",
    previewTemplate: "<div></div>"
});
```

The other part is the progress bar. To accomplish this, you could add an event listener for [addedfile](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-addedfile) to create your progress bar

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
     // Build progress bar here
});
```

Then, use the [totaluploadprogress](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-totaluploadprogress) event from dropzone to update the progress on your progress bar:

```
myDropzone.on("totaluploadprogress", function(progress) {
    // Update progress bar with the value in the variable "progress", which 
    // is the % total upload progress from 0 to 100
});
```

Hopefully this points you in the right direction. There will of course be other cleanup needed, like when to hide the total progress bar, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it seems to not hide everything, setting the preview template to an empty div, still getting a line with the path of the uploaded item for every item.... You know why?

Comment: my bad, was a mistake in my code (the php-file uploading the files), gonna get back to you if the rest is working

Comment: **Edit**: it not works perfectly, the progress of the progress bar is always jumping arounnd, because I also give the possibility to upload folders, and then it always realizes that there are more files in the subfolders and then the progress is just "jumping back" again, etc... Do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: Hmm I am not sure. You could see if there is a way to not show the progress bar until items are finished queueing but I don't know if there is an easy way to do that just with the events in dropzone

Comment: The problem is that it seems like it goes trough the folders recursively and detects the items in the folders, but in the meantime already starts uploading, so it might be, that once all files are queued, the uploads already finished, you know what I mean?